# JTable AutoSorter em colunas

Tags: java, jtable, rowsorter

Pessoal estou a alguns anos com uma dificuldade que ainda hoje nao consegui resolver completamente. Ao adicionar um `TableRowSorter`  a um `JTable` automaticamente as colunas podem ser ordenadas ao clicar e com isso tenho um problema em pegar a index correta, sim ja tentei usar o `ConvertIndexToView` e `ConvertIndexToModel` , ja procurei em varios locais em como desativar a opção de autosorter ao clicar nas colunas mas sem sucesso.

Aqui esta funcionando perfeitamente selecionei a index 1 e o registro veio correto conforme o numero selecionado
[image: Aqui esta funcionando perfeitamente selecionei a index 1 e o registro veio correto conforme o numero selecionado]

Segunda Imagem com o erro, ja neste selecionei a index 1 e com o filtro ativo conforme mostrado me puxa o mesmo registro que na imagem anterior diferente da view

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Apos conversar com o Articuno descobri o erro no meu codigo verifiquei o exemplo da oracle que funcionava perfeitamente e verifiquei a linha do codigo onde eu obtinha os objetos do modelo o meu estava assim:

```
@Override
public generics getObjeto(int rowIndex) {    
   //Se a quantidade de linhas do modelo não fosse igual  da tabela
   if (tabela.getModel().getRowCount() != tabela.getRowCount()) {
        //Converta a linha para a index do modelo
        return linhas.get(tabela.convertRowIndexToModel(rowIndex));
    } else { 
         //Se não sao diferentes jogue a index para o modelo sem converter      
        return linhas.get(rowIndex);
    }
}
```

Apos analizar o exemplo eu removi o codigo desnecessario ficando da seguinte forma:

```
@Override
    public generics getObjeto(int rowIndex) {    
        return linhas.get(tabela.convertRowIndexToModel(rowIndex));       
    }
```

Obrigado ao Articuno pela enorme paciencia, prometo melhorar as postagens.

Comment: Adicione um **[mcve]** do seu código para que seja possivel testar o problema.

Comment: Vou reproduzir o meu problema e  tentar mostrar em imagem

Comment: Veja isso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/28595

Comment: A sim! eu costumo postar o codigo inteiro mas neste caso envolve muitas classes, o modelo que uso no jtable é personalizado e tambem nao uso o proprio jtable eu adaptei usando o patter Decoretor por isso postei desta forma so para que entende-se o meu erro. Mas eu de certa forma resolvi travando a coluna e estou vendo o que me mandou do demo da propria oracle vou ver se fiz algo errado durante o procedimento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui apos muita pequisa uma forma para desativar o autosorter que acontecia ao clicar nas colunas do `JTable` bastou sobreescrever o metodo `isSortable`  do `TableRowSorter` para retornar `false` para todas as colunas assim ao clicar nas colunas o usuario nao consegue mais ordenar os dados.

```
TableRowSorter sorter = new TableRowSorter(tabela.getModel()){
            @Override
            public boolean isSortable(int column) {
                return false; 
            }            
        };
```

Comment: Então o problema era a ordenação no cabeçalho da coluna e não recuperar o indice correto?

Comment: O problema era que quando ordenado nao recuperava os objetos que estavam no List pois o indice da lista era diferente do indice do modelo da view. Quando uso o para pesquisar um JTable baseando em uma String eu resolvia esse problema da index da Lista e a Index da View usando o convertIndextoView. Mas Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Reproduzi seu problema e `convertRowIndexToModel` funcionou corretamente. O problema não era esse, com certeza, é na forma como você está fazendo essa conversão. Isso resolve, mas só "mascara" o problema. Execute esse exemplo da oracle e veja que o indice do model não muda: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TableFilterDemo

Comment: Voce tinha toda razão vou postar como estava o codigo antes e a correção.